# Recibir distintos objetos con una interfaz común

Tags: java, herencia, polimorfismo

Quiero que la clase C sea pueda recibir como argumento la clase A o B (comparten algunos metodos), tal como se haría en un lenguaje dinámico. ¿Existe algun patron de diseño o alguna otra manera de resolver esto?

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public void saludar() {
        //...
    }
}

public class B {
    public B() {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public void saludar() {
        //...
    }
}

public class C {
    public C(X controller) {
        controller.saludar();
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes crear una interfaz para el metodo saludar y en la clase c recibir como argumentos el tipo de la clase interfaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entiendo bien que es lo que deseas, pero te dejo este código haber si te ayuda en algo.

```
public class Main {

    public static class A{
        A(){

        }
        void saludar(){
            System.out.println("saludo de A");
        }
    }
    public static class B{
        B(){

        }
        void saludar(){
            System.out.println("saludo de B");
        }
    }
    public static class C{
        Object obj=null;
        C(Object controller){
            if(controller instanceof A){
                obj=new A();
            }else{
                obj=new B();
            }
        }
        void saludar(){
            System.out.print("saludando desde C junto al ");
            if(obj instanceof A){
                ((A) obj).saludar();
            }else{
                ((B) obj).saludar();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        a.saludar();
        B b=new B();
        b.saludar();
        C c_a=new C(a);
        c_a.saludar();
        C c_b=new C(b);
        c_b.saludar();
    }

}
```

El cual imprime:

> saludo de A
>   saludo de B
>   saludando desde C junto al saludo de A
>   saludando desde C junto al saludo de B

Answer (score 1):

Realmente puedes pasar toda una clase como argumento para extraer el contenido de interes de la misma

```
public class A extends claseB{ //usas directamente los metodos de la 
                               //clase  B a traves de la herencia, 
                               //pero solo lo puedes hacer con una clase

 }
```

Otra manera seria

```
public class A {
   private B claseB = null;

    public A(B claseB){
       this.claseB = claseB; // aqui retienes la clase B y puedes acceder 
       a sus metodos y atributos que estes dispuesto a traves de los
       setter y getter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sin abusar de herencia, podrias simplemente implementar una interfaz comun `X` de la siguiente forma:

```
public interface X{
    void saludar();
}

public class A implements X{
    public A() {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public void saludar() {
        //...
    }
}

public class B implements X{
    public B() {
        C c = new C(this);
    }

    public void saludar() {
        //...
    }
}

public class C {
    public C(X controller) {
        controller.saludar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

según yo entiendo la pregusta eso en java es fácil simplemente tendrías que crear en la clase C dos constructores, un constructor que recibe como parámetro la clase A y otro que recibo como parámetro la clase B tan sencillo como eso:
Tu clase C quedaría de esta manera.

```
public class C {
private A a;
private B b;

    public C(A a) {
        this.a=a;
        a.saludar();
    }
    public C(B b){
        this.b=b;
        b.saludar();
    }
}
```

Y de esta forma podras invocar la clase C con cualquiera de los dos argumentos y podras ejecutar cualquier procedimiento dependiendo del parametro que le pasen al invicarlo. Por ejemplo:

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        C c = new C(this);//en ese caso c ejecutaria el metodo saludar de la clase A aun que eso solo es un ejemplo por que si fuera de forma real seria una redundancia terrible ya si lo que deseas es invocar el metodo saludar no tienes que instancear otra clase que lo haga.
    }

    public void saludar() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva.